# Как на C++ скопировать текст в буфер обмена

Tags: python, c++, функции

Недавно сделал попытку перейти с `python` на `C++`, чтобы ускорить работу кода и мне понадобилась моя старая функция

```
import pyperclip
def set_cp(s):
    pyperclip.copy(s)
```

Окей, в `C++` надо выделять память и т.д., нашел несколько таких функций:

- Из видео:

```
void TextToClipboard(char *text)
{
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        char *hBuff = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strlen(text) + 1);
        strcpy(hBuff, text);
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hBuff);
        CloseClipboard();

    }
}
```

Тут  проблема в том, что пишет `невозможно преобразовать "HGLOBAL" в "char *"`

---

- [с сайта](http://netcode.ru/cpp/?lang=&katID=3&skatID=22&artID=248):

```
CString source; //в эту переменную нужно записать текст, который в дальнейшем поместится в буфер обмена
//запись текста в буфер обмена
if(OpenClipboard())//открываем буфер обмена
{
   HGLOBAL hgBuffer;
   char* chBuffer;
   EmptyClipboard(); //очищаем буфер
   hgBuffer= GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE, source.GetLength()+1);//выделяем память
   chBuffer= (char*)GlobalLock(hgBuffer); //блокируем память
   strcpy(chBuffer, LPCSTR(source));
   GlobalUnlock(hgBuffer);//разблокируем память
   SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hgBuffer);//помещаем текст в буфер обмена
   CloseClipboard(); //закрываем буфер обмена
}
```

Здесь `идентификатор CString не определен` и еще куча ошибок + это вообще не функция.

Как такое реализовать, чтобы я мог записать string в буфер обмена (возможно и не string, если лучше не его) и все это в виде функции?

Также какие инклуды и пространства имен нужно подключить, если нужно?

P.S. как же у вас это все тяжело...

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard

Comment: Судя по приведенному коду, в примере который вы взяли за основу используется MFC - отсюда и куча ошибок, соответственно вам нужно либо подключить эти библиотеки или создать проект на их  основе. Как пользоваться буфером без MFC привел ссылку @user7860670 . Ну и не лишним будет почитать как строится программа на С++

Answer (score 1):

Воткнул (char *) куда следует и заработало. Успехов!

```
void TextToClipboard(char *text)
 {
    if (OpenClipboard(0))
    {
        EmptyClipboard();
        char *hBuff = (char *) GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, strlen(text) + 1);
        strcpy(hBuff, text);
        SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hBuff);
        CloseClipboard();

    }
}
```

Comment: Текст в буфер тоже скопировался или только откомпилировалось?